# Mocking WCF RIA services in Silverlight - specification of submit operation response

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mocking, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to mock WCF RIA services on the Silverlight side following [WCF RIA Services Part 8 - Testing and Debugging](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-8-Testing-and-Debugging.aspx) post.
I am injecting `DomainClient` into `DomainContext` and implementing its abstract methods in the mock.
However implementing the protocol is more or less a guess work since I was not able to find any guidance / specification.
*(I actually wrapped the default `DomainClient` and used the debugger to learn the communication details).*

- For Queries I learned how to use Entities and IncludedEntities properties on the `QueryCompletedResult` class and that I need to "associate" them via foreign keys.
- Submit is more tricky. I am not sure how to craft the proper `SubmitCompletedResult` as a response to the `ChangeSet`. I would like to mock correct behavior as well as some error scenarios.

**Questions**:

1. Is there and documentation about the protocol? Commented code sample for Submit operation implementation would be great.
2. Is somebody successfully using the same pattern for unit testing Silverlight applications? What is your experience?
3. Is there any other approach how to mock WCF RIA services in Silverlight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually studying the same article at the time being. There is an example you can download. The whole Submit and Query operations of MockDomainClient are implemented in there. (The article shows only one or two).

The only remaining challenge is implmenting the Invoke operations, which he left out to do later. :(

hope that helps,
Kave

Comment: I downloaded the sample code, but it works only for simple scenarios. For example in Query scenario I needed to enhance it by using included entities. For submit the code does not work as expected for more complex operations (multiple add/update/delete operations in on SubmitChanges call).  The question was about the guidelines/specification how to implement more complex scenarios, beyond the scope of the sample code presented in article.